# javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Tags: jsf

I'm making a project to school in JSF and I have few problems with that.

First of all, the h:commandButton doesn't work properly when I want to redirect myself to another page of the project by pushing it. There is an error displayed:

javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

index.jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <head>
<title>Firma Komputerowa - Baza Danych</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/table-style.css" />
  </head>
     <body>
       <f:view>
         <h:form>   
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
     <h:commandButton action="#{producentBean.redirect }" value="Dodaj"/>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:dataTable value="#{producentBean.List}" var="p" 
                styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row" border="1" > 
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">ID producenta</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.getId}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nazwa producenta</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.getNazwa}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">NIP</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.getNip}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">REGON</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.getRegon}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Miasto</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.getMiasto}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Adres</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.getAdres}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Telefon</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.getTel}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">E-mail</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.getEmail}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
       </f:view>
    ...
   </body>
</html>
```

ProducentBean.java:

```
    public class ProducentBean extends Polacz implements Serializable {

   public String redirect() {
    return "dodaj_pr";
}
}
```

I was trying to do it in many ways, but I can't deal with it.

I also have an another question: is there in JSF a possibility to display a table dynamically from database, for example by choosing a table name selecting an option in ? My database contains three tables with different count of colums each.

I'll be very happy if somebody gives me some advices.

---

EDIT:

OK, I tried to do this:

```
private String dodajPrUrl = "dodaj_pr?faces-redirect=true";

public String getDodajPrUrl() {
    return this.dodajPrUrl;
}

public void setDodajPrUrl(String newUrl) {
    this.dodajPrUrl = newUrl;
}
```

and in index.jsp:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{producentBean.redirect }" value="Dodaj" />
```

It gives me still the same error.

### EDIT2:

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for  Set Operation
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:853)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:735)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:2001)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.processUpdates(UIData.java:1253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1231)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:207)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:291)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:818)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: `redirect` method should return a `String` not `void`. You're getting the exception because you're attempting to bind a `value` in your view without exposing it using javabean convention (getter and setter) in your backing bean

Comment: You need to go through some JSF hello world. Start [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/)

Comment: I followed by this tutorial, especially the Implicit navigation in JSF 2.0 section, but it doesn't matter which way I go - the error is still displayed. I use JSF2.0 with Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Eclipse Juno. The file has got an .jsp extension and is mapped to .jsf. Please, could You tell me, what the problem is and how to solve it? I have really done everything I can.

Comment: Can you show us whole code inside `<form>..</form>`, and getters and setters in bean?

Comment: @user2014064, well at least you've done some research. Post the full stack trace here along with your bean code

Comment: You're trying to use JSF 2 with JSP. Drop that and start using Facelets (the xhtml files) as shown in [our JSF wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: I know it will be better using Facelets, but my teacher said, that it must be JSP.

Comment: @user2014064 I have one question, why did you write in title questions about "<h:commandButton> and <h:selectOneMenu>"? I don't see any `selectOneMenu` here.

Comment: Because of my second question about dynamic displaying a table from database. I'm thinking about using the 'selectOneMenu' for that. However, I want to solve my main problem with a 'commandButton' first.

Comment: In my case it was a problem of conversion types.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look at the stack trace. Here's the most important part:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:853)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:735)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:2001)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.processUpdates(UIData.java:1253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1231)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    ... 26 more
```

Read from bottom to top. During update model values phase, JSF is traversing the component tree starting from `UIViewRoot` component (`<f:view>`). In an `UIForm` component (`<h:form>`) there is an `UIData` component (`<h:dataTable>`) which has an `UIInput` component (`<h:inputText>`) which needs to be processed. The `updateModel()` basically needs to put the submitted, converted and validated value in the model (the managed bean). However, that operation has failed because the property is not writable (i.e. the setter method cannot be found based on the EL expression syntax).

Well, let's look at the properties of your `<h:inputText>` components in general.

```
<h:inputText value="#{p.getId}"/>
...
<h:inputText value="#{p.getNazwa}" />
...
<h:inputText value="#{p.getNip}" />
```

Wait, that's strange. They start all with "get"! This is definitely not normal. JSF is then looking for methods like `setGetId()`, `setGetNazwa()`, etc which just doesn't make sense (and you likely also don't have, given this exception). It's expected that they represent concrete property names like "id", "nazwa", "nip", etc and not full method names.

Thus, so in the model:

```
private Long id;
private String nazwa;
private String nip;

// Add/generate getters and setters in the following syntax:

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

// ...
```

And so in the view:

```
<h:inputText value="#{p.id}"/>
...
<h:inputText value="#{p.nazwa}" />
...
<h:inputText value="#{p.nip}" />
```

This is however already covered in a bit sane JSF book/tutorial/resource. Are you absolutely positive that you were reading the right one? Your question also shows that you're using JSF 2.0 in combination with the *deprecated* JSP view technology instead of its successor Facelets. Start at [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: OK, I try to remake my Bean and an index file. Unfortunately, I have to combine JSF with JSP, because that was the "order" of my weird teacher.

Comment: Correcting that I solved my problem, thank You very much;) For any reasons I missed Your JSF Wiki Page and I was mixing advices from many different guidebooks. Now, it's time to go to bigger problems in my project;)

Comment: You're welcome. The wiki page can be found by among others hovering the question tag until a black box shows up and then clicking the *info* link.

Answer (score 3):

You have few problems here. First, in your input components you have values like `p.getId`. In your bean, you probably have methods called `getId` and `setId`, but this means that you have property called just `id` which you can read and write. So change your values to: `p.id`, `p.nazwa`, `p.nip`... You can see that I'm using all lower letters, not **Id** but **id**.

Second, you should change your action method to something like this (if you want redirect):

```
public String redirect() {
  return "dodaj_pr?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

and command button tag to something like this:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{producentBean.redirect}" value="Dodaj" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same mistake. The error was that in the value property of the inputext in the EL there were blank spaces between } and "  as shown below.

```
<h:inputText id="txtNroOficio" value="# {bean.nombre}  "   />
```

I deleted the blank spaces and it worked.

Comment: Below where? I don't see anything. You need to edit your answer

Comment: I'm sorry, here's the code.  <h:inputText id="txtNroOficio" value="#{bean.nombre} 
 "

Comment: I still improved it. Look at the differences on how to show code in answers

Comment: Kukeltje Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Don't give the () in your command button. In your bean method return some string and use navigation to move to another page.