# javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException:Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, scope, el

I have a quite troublesome problem with JSF (myfaces 1.1, xhtml) when updating the model. For example this snippet (inside a column of a datatable) works quite well when rendering:

```
<t:inputText value="#{interlocuteur.commercial.nom} " id="pop_out_4365" />
```

But when submitting I get the exception. So I ran in debug mode and here is the stack:

[image: Stack trace to the exception]

When I look into the code, the exception is happening there:

```
public void setValue(EvaluationContext ctx, Object value)
        throws ELException {
    throw new PropertyNotWritableException(MessageFactory.get("error.syntax.set"));
}
```

As you can see it seems there was almost no chance to escape it. I think this might be the default behavior for when it does not retrieve the correct node and uses a default node which does not override that method.

All of this makes me guessing this might be a scope related problem: Indeed, if the original datatable structure has been stored in a request-scope, when submitting it would not be able to find it back? But as for my model, I already controlled that it is stored in a session-scoped bean so I think the update should work if it reaches this part of the code.

Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540153/javax-el-propertynotwritableexception-illegal-syntax-for-set-operation) on same topic, but my problem seems different, please provide hints about what to check to make sure the datatable structure is updated as intended, because I am a little out of imagination about where to investigate next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why, but after submitting the question, I had a flash: The trailing space in the snipet was the key:

```
<t:inputText value="#{interlocuteur.commercial.nom} " id="pop_out_4365" />
```

Not a problem for an outputText, but inputText don't like it. Sorry for bothering you.